# Simple Regex for url ended by / not working on each case

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using the following regex in a .htaccess file

```
RewriteRule ^((?!blog).)*\/([A-Za-z0-9\/-]+)$  controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L,R=301]

^((?!blog).)*\/([A-Za-z0-9\/-]+)$
```

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/bAhiWHP-VNEliO-E)

this make the following url redirected

```
www.mysite.com/my/page/
```

*but not this one*

```
www.mysite.com/mypage/
```

Any idea why the second url is not redirected while both are ok in regex tester ?

EDIT the .htaccess file as asked, I can clean the file if necessary :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ndd1.fr$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^ddp.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ddp.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ddp.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ddp.eu
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ddp.eu
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} peluche.ddp.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} dds.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ddl.eu
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ddl.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ddpe.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ddp.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ddp.eu
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.dds.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ddl.eu
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ddl.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ddpe.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ddp.fr
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.ddp.eu
RewriteRule ^(.*)   http://www.ddp.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]

RewriteRule ^liste/(.*)$ /listes.php?listeUrl=$1 [qsappend,L]

# REDIRECT BAD URL TO 404
# eg : http://www.ddp.com/page/mypage/
RewriteRule ^((?!blog).)*\/([A-Za-z0-9\/-]+)$  controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L]

# eg : www.ddp.com/page..   OR www.ddp.com/page..mypage
RewriteRule ^(.*\.\.).*[a-z]*$ controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L]

# eg : www.ddp.com/page-produit-1-to-40.html
RewriteRule ^.*(-produit-|-Produit-).*$ controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L]

# eg : www.ddp.com/page-moins-de-24-euro.html
RewriteRule ^.*(-moins-|-Moins-).*$ controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L]

RewriteRule ^.*(home-sites).*$ controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L]
RewriteRule ^.*(com_).*$ controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L]
RewriteRule ^.*(%20).*$ controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L]
RewriteRule ^.*(V4).*$ controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L]
RewriteRule ^.*(htmll).*$ controller.php?action=nopage [qsappend,L]

RewriteRule (^.*)\.(.*)\.html$  controller.php?rewriteKey=$1&rewriteParams=$2 [qsappend,L]
RewriteRule (^.*)\.html$  controller.php?rewriteKey=$1 [qsappend,L]
RewriteRule monpanier controller.php?action=showFunnel
RewriteRule monadresse controller.php?action=showFunnel
```

Comment: @anubhava: thx but it's not working => The requested URL /mypage/ was not found on this server.  instead of having a redirection like /controller.php?action=nopage

Comment: What is filesystem location of this .htaccess? Can you copy/paste code from your latest .htaccess?

Comment: I don't see my suggested rule here. btw my rules should be placed in bottom since that catches every URI.

Comment: I tyied by replacing the string ^(.*\.\.).*[a-z]*$

Comment: the regex is not working [Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/SK2pX01WTBVGTKyZ)

Comment: YES it's working fine now ^^ THX very much can you pls explain a little bit the process ?

Comment: yes sure how may I do that just with a comment ?

Comment: You need to click on tick mark on top-left of my answer (it give you more reps also). This is how stackoverflow system works.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation..I need 15 ! I'll do it once I'll have enough point ^^ thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this regex in your rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((?!blog)[A-Za-z0-9/-]+)/?$ controller.php?action=nopage [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Make sure this rule is in the bottom.

Comment: check updated rule and let me for what URL it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason your regex is catching the `m` in `.com`. This regex seems to solve that:

```
^(?:(?!blog).)*?\/([A-Za-z0-9\/-]+)$
```